# Error of 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined', it comes start to end or vice-versa of application window by moving mouse wheel scroll

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I am working on qml, found found an error during moving mouse wheel scrolling i.e.

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined".

It only appear when either mouse wheel scrolling or close the application while during execution and beginning of the application didn't show this error.

One more thing, I am getting accurate data/result whatever I want but due to this error the performance of application get affected.

Please let me know how can I get rid of this issue?

also find below example to see error.

My code is..

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    TableView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        visible: true
        backgroundVisible: false
        alternatingRowColors: false
        sortIndicatorVisible: true
        clip: true
        highlightOnFocus: false
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height


        TableViewColumn{ role: "code"  ; title: "cde" ; width: 200;
            delegate: Component {
                id: codeDelegate
                Item{
                Text {
                    color: "lightgray"
                    elide: styleData.elideMode
                    text: styleData.value //modelSettingData.get(styleData.row).name
                    font.family: "Arial"
                    font.pixelSize: 18
                    wrapMode: Text.WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere

                    Text {
                        id: metaData
                        color: "red"
                        width: parent.width
                       // height: 20
                        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                        anchors.bottomMargin: -parent.height/1.5
                        font.weight: Font.ExtraLight
                        //elide: Text.ElideMiddle
                        text: "Time: " + modelSettingData.get(styleData.row).name  //Error comes when this part added but I need to use it with the same form
                    }
                }
                }
            }

        }
        TableViewColumn{ role: "name" ; title: "nme" ; width: 200
            delegate: Component {
                id: nameDelegate
                Text {
                    color: "yellow"
                    elide: styleData.elideMode
                    text: styleData.value
                    font.family: "Arial"
                    font.pixelSize: 18
                }
            }

        }

        model: ListModel {
            id: modelSettingData
            ListElement {
                name: "aaaaaaaaaa"
                code: "3042666666666"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "bbbbbb"
                code: "32235"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "ccccccc"
                code: "32638"
            }

            ListElement {
                name: "ddddddddddd"
                code: "00000000000"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "eeeeeeeeeeee"
                code: "111111111111"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "ffffffffffff"
                code: "222222222222"
            }

            ListElement {
                name: "ggggggggggggg"
                code: "3333333333333"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "hhhhhhhhhhhhh"
                code: "4444444444444"
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "iiiiiiiiiiiii"
                code: "5555555555555"
            }
        }
        rowDelegate: Rectangle {
            property bool selected : styleData.selected
            width: parent.width-2
            height: 100
            color: styleData.selected? "black" : "black"
            Rectangle {
                width: parent.width
                height: 1
                anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
                visible: parent.selected
                color: "yellow"
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For some reason, I have not found now, the `styleData.row` is -1, when the error is thrown. A short fix (that will disable the error, but does not fix the origin) would be `Math.max(0, styleData.row)`.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a bug. If I had to guess, I'd say it is due to the row delegate recycling that `TableView` does, but it's surprising that it hasn't been noticed until now.

Comment: A little remark: Yo have set `anchors.fill: parent` as well as `width: parent.width; height: parent.height` for your TableView. Don't do that ;-)

Comment: Isn't it the note [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#itemDelegate-prop): *"For performance reasons, created delegates can be recycled across multiple table rows. This implies that **when you make use of implicit properties such as styleData.row or model, these values can change after the delegate has been constructed**. This means that you should not assume that content is fixed when Component.onCompleted is called, but instead rely on bindings to such properties."*??